# Center selected tab in SlidingTabLayout/SlidingTabStrip

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation

I am using the SlidingTabLayout.java and SlidingTabStrip.java classes to implement a tab navigation inside my app like described [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout).

Everything works fine and I really love this two classes. But I would like to center the selected tab (whether navigated through slide or click on the tab) to be in the middle of tab navigation. Right now it is always on the left side (except when you reach the end of the tab navigation than it is right). Also when you click on a tab the navigation scrolls back to the current tab and scrolls then to the tab you just selected. Is there anyway to stop this scrolling and just to center the clicked tab?

Using the method

```
slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
```

does not do the trick.

I tried to read through the code and find a good starting point but I did not succeed. Does anyone know how to achieve that? Any good advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would think that tabs would be automatically centred if you need to scroll to view tabs (i.e. there are a lot of tabs that do not fit without scrolling).

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the case that is why I am asking. :)